# Having trouble understanding how to stay on topic

Tags: discussion, scope, homework-and-exercises

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [What governs the temperature rise inside an oven?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374275/what-governs-the-temperature-rise-inside-an-oven)

I find myself frustrated with how questions need to be asked... and the pit of 'On Hold / Closed'.

I asked a question to understand and learn about a problem Id like to, even if only on paper, design a solution to.

In this question I provided as much information that was 'on topic' [:)] with all my working... I had tried solving the problem of the design and wanted to confirm that I had indeed used the correct physics concepts (And associated equations), which Im still skeptical about.

The question was put on hold within 1 hour.

So I created another question asking the same thing but dumbed it down, removed the equations and made no mention of having tried to learn about the topic before asking the question... and removed the homework and exercises tag (Reading more in meta; this may be the culprit).

This question, linked above, attracted some comments and an edit that included other tags. But it was not put on hold.

Why is that?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused... where's the original post? I'm not finding any other than the one you linked....

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374197/calculate-the-power-required-to-heat-air-in-a-plaster-enclosure Was this the other question?  It seemed to fit your description somewhat.

Comment: Yup, thats the one; I did not have access to work to log in, though it was bothering me enough to create another account. Otherwise it has been flagged as too broad since.

Comment: If you'd like to merge your two accounts (which is probably a good idea), [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).